# Detect a subscription in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I need to know if my player has an active subscription (that hasn't been expired or cancelled) and if that is true (subscribtion has expired or has been cancelled), set the game exclusive rewards to default values. I just only need to know how to check the subscription, does anyone know?
Thanks.

Comment: PS: My subscribtion and IAP Products are just signed in Google Play, My app will not be in App Store for now.

Comment: if(!activeSubscription) gameExclusiveRewards = defaultValues; . not sure how your code is setup. perhaps a snippet of what you've done?

Comment: @comphonia I just modified the default code that is in the Unity documentation, and the rewards are just variables stored in the PlayerPrefs, like, if the player buys 200 coins in the store, the code line will be (after all the purchase comprobation in play store): PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Coins", Add200CoinsInt); Do you really need all the code? ;D Also, ActiveSubscription is on a class or something like that?

Comment: What purchasing API are you using?

Comment: @Draco18s I'm using Unity In App Purchase with setting the Product IDs in the Google Developer Console

Comment: Unity's IAP is just a wrapper around Google's Play Store API or Apple's App Store API. That's it. Unity does not in any way supply a backend.

Comment: Like Dracos said Unity just gives you an abstraction to make it easier to access the api, if you have implemented it as far as setting an active subscription, you can make a call to it to return the active subscription value then set the PlayerPrefs value to its default depending on the result.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPSubscriptionProducts.html

Comment: @comphonia So... Its something like... if (IsCancelled())? Its an enum so I dont know, I guess this is the right way

Comment: an enum is something like ... enum Results{true, false}; and can be accessed by using Results.true or Results.false